# What replaced the method clone(Serializable)

Tags: java, gwt, clone

I would like to know and understand what exacly replaced the metod BaseService.clone(Serializable).

I Have this code:

```
          if (type == 1) {
            evenement = (Evenemen) clone(evenement);
            evenement.setCdtype(TypeEvenement.toString());
          }
```

Here `evenement` is a class with strings, integers and arrays.

and eclipse tell me that warning:

> The method clone(Serializable) from the type BaseService is deprecated

So my question is what replaced the clone method?

I have tried searchig for a solution but everywhere, I just read to put a `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")`, I dont want to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing replaced. But your `copy constructor` definitely will. Make a copy constructor in your class

For Example :

```
Class SomeClass{

   private String testString ;

   public SomeClass(SomeClass obj) {
    this.testString = obj.testString;  
  }

}
```

When you define a class by extending above class, you need to define a similar constructor there also. In child class, you need to copy child specific attributes and pass the argument to super class’s constructor